# How to find the optimal combination of numbers based on set guidelines?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The example I present is about staffing for a hotel, in this example the team would establish an arbitrary number for guests leaving (departures) and guests who need service that day (stay-overs). The system I want to create is a way for it to take those numbers and formulate the most optimal amount of Staff members needed to complete the amount of rooms while maintaining efficiency. In addition to that there is guidelines that must be followed, one Staff Member can only have one combination already presented, for example 9/2 or 8/4. They can't mix and match the guidelines, for example 9/4 or 8/2. I am looking for some ideas and inspiration to start this problem. Any help would be beyond helpful!

Snapshot of Example:

[image: Snapshot of Example]

At this moment I have built my visualization for it, but I don't know where to begin as far as the logic goes or if this is something that is capable with current excel capabilities.

Comment: You need a cell for profit (revenue - salary) then you can use Goal Seek to obtain the profit you specify.

Comment: This function is normally used in a single variable scenario like you're explaining, but I can't see how this function could pertain to a multi variable scenario with some variables being dependent of one another. Moreover, I have no need to gather the profit in this example I am wanting to find the most optimal work assignments for staff members that falls in line with the given guidelines. I appreciate the feedback, but I don't see a linear line from your feedback to my solution.

Comment: I think your explanation could use a little more detail.  I see you have a 'resource' in the upper left corner that you want to divide among a variable number of staff.  Are the guidelines maximum constraints?  If so, then just

Comment: [Comment continued]...   If so, then put an integer next to each constraint indicating number of staff bound by that constraint, sum them up and minimize that number using the SOLVER add-in.  You'll need 2 additional constraints of each number multiplied by its maximum departure and multiplied by its maximum stayover to meet the resource pool.

Comment: I apologize if the explanation was insufficient. The "resource" is a variable number that will change each day, from that number I want to know what is the minimum amount of staffing would be needed that satisfies the guidelines. Once an amount of staff is provided I then want to find the best possible combination of Departures/Stayovers that is equal to the guideline. I am unsure if I am accurately explaining everything. The Solver Add-in is a new tool to me, If possible could you shine a little light into how you attempt to solve this?

Comment: So the combination of the guidelines are repeatable? I mean, can multiple employees "perform" 8 departures and 4 stayovers, for instance?

Comment: @P.b Yes, the combinations are repeatable while still using the minimum number of employees. If the program decided the most optimal combination for 5 employees was all 8/4 that is okay. It could even tell me that for 2 employees 8/4 and the other three 9/2 resulting in a more optimized workload.